# efficient parsing xml with php

Tags: php, xml

Is this the most efficient way to retrieve these xml elements using php? It is not too long but the three nested loops seems a bit weighty and just doesn't feel right.

Thank you very much,
Todd

```
// get the existing xml file
$url = '../../page_xml/index.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); // == Root tag

// get the sliderImages node
foreach($xml->Page as $page){
    foreach($page->sliderImages as $sliderImages){
        foreach($sliderImages->sliderImage as $sliderImage){
            echo "<strong>Title:</strong> ".$sliderImage."<br/>";

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root type="content">
  <Page>
    <hMenuHighlight>home</hMenuHighlight>
    <pageName>Home</pageName>

    <sliderImages>
        <sliderImage>images/home_slider/paper_bag.jpg</sliderImage>
        <sliderImage>images/home_slider/red_box.jpg</sliderImage>
        <sliderImage>images/home_slider/cubes.jpg</sliderImage>
        <sliderImage>images/home_slider/gift_boxes.jpg</sliderImage>        
    </sliderImages>


    <pageText>
    <![CDATA[
        <h1>Welcome to myShopName</h1>

        <!-- Start SLIDER IMAGES -->
        <div id="slideshow">
            <!--##mySlideshowImages-->
        </div>
        <!-- End SLIDER IMAGES -->

        <p>Puzzle Logo image provided by <a href="http://www.logoease.com">Logoease</a>.</p>
        <p>Paper bag image provided by <a href="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/view_photog.php?photogid=1012">Felixco, Inc. / FreeDigitalPhotos.net</a>.</p>
        <p>Red Box image provided by <a href="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/view_photog.php?photogid=1058">Arvind Balaraman / FreeDigitalPhotos.net</a>.</p>
        <p>Cubes image provided by <a href="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/view_photog.php?photogid=1152">jscreationzs / FreeDigitalPhotos.net</a></p>
        <p>Gift boxes image provided by <a href="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/view_photog.php?photogid=1152">jscreationzs / FreeDigitalPhotos.net</a></p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>

    ]]>
    </pageText>
  </Page>
</Root>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the `XML`? 3 nested loops seems bulky.

Comment: It is bulky, the xml needs to be "deep" to work with a couple of add ons I am using.

Comment: I guess a more fitting term would have been condensed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`simplexml_load_file`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) returns an object, you can do:

```
foreach ( $xml->Page->sliderImages->sliderImage as $sliderImage )
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one <Page> tag and one <sliderImages> tag, then you can do:

```
$si_list = $xml->Page->sliderImages;
foreach($si_list as $si)
    echo "<strong>Title:</strong> " . $si . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what I was envisioning. I chose Ahmed's answer because it is more efficient,less lines, etc. I think this one is easier to "follow" though.